# Performing complex searchs using C# collections

Tags: c#, algorithms, collections

I have a collection with millions of items of Generic type T. Assume this list never changes.
I want to perform many types of searches with subsets of fields of type T. Some with only 1 field and others with 2 or more fields.
Each search almost always returns more than 1 result.

This answer is very close to what I want but it only works for searches with only one field:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/multiple-indexes-over-an-in-memory-collection-for-faster-search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can use the code just like in link you posted. And call it like this:

```
  var fc = new FastCollection<Product>(products);

  fc.AddIndex(item => new { UserName = item.UserName, Title = item.Title});

  string userName = "...";
  string title = "...";

  // finds items where UserName == userName and Title == title
  var items = 
     fc.FindValue(
        item => new { UserName = item.UserName, Title = item.Title}, 
                new { UserName = userName     , Title = title })
        .ToArray();
```

This code makes use of anonymous types to create a single "property" that is aggregate of multiple properties.

This also reminds me how indexes are done in RavenDB.

Comment: Yes that seems to be what I really want! Thanks! The catch here is that I always have to add the index before I perform the search.. if I have 10 different searches I have to add 10 different indexes.. meh.

Comment: @deeproute Well, you can change the code of the FastCollection, so that it adds new index if it doesn't find one, instead of falling back to Where. I actually assumed it was doing just that before I double-checked the code.